# Kак показать все элементы многомерного массива с рекурсией?

Tags: javascript, массивы

```
let x = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, [6, 7, [8, 9], 10, 11], 12], 13, [14]];
```

Как показать все элементы многомерного массива с помощью рекурсии?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Современный вариант:

Метод [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) возвращает новый массив, в котором все элементы вложенных подмассивов были рекурсивно "подняты" на указанный уровень depth.

```js
const x = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, [6, 7, [8, 9], 10, 11], 12], 13, [14]];
x.flat(Infinity).map((el) => console.log(el))
```

Cовременный вариант с использованием рекурсивного [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) и [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```js
function flattenDeep(arr1) {
    return arr1.reduce((acc, val) =>
        Array.isArray(val) ? acc.concat(flattenDeep(val)) : acc.concat(val), []);
}

const x = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, [6, 7, [8, 9], 10, 11], 12], 13, [14]];
console.log(flattenDeep(x));
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let x = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, [6, 7, [8, 9], 10, 11], 12], 13, [14]];

function print(elements) {
  for (const element of elements) {
    if (Array.isArray(element)) {
      print(element)
    } else {
      console.log(element);
    }
  }
}

print(x)
```

Comment: данная функа может быть переписана так : 
`const print = elements => elements.forEach(e => Array.isArray(e) ? print(e) : console.log(e))`